# Quotient of a nonconstant meromorphic function on a hyperelliptic curve

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a hyperelliptic curve, and let $f:X\to \Bbb P^1$ be the degree 2 map induced by hyperelliptic involution. By elementary properties of holomorphic maps, $f$ is surjective, continuous, and open, so it is a quotient map. Suppose $g$ be a nonconstant meromorphic function on $X$, viewed as a holomorphic map $X\to \Bbb P^1$, and that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $g(x)=g(y)$. Then $f$ induces a unique continuous map $h:\Bbb P^1\to \Bbb P^1$ such that $g=hf$. How can we show that $h$ is holomorphic?

If $x\in X$ is not a ramification point of $f$, then $f$ is a local biholomorphism at $x$, so $h$ is holomorphic at $f(x)$. But I can't show that $h$ is holomorphic at the $2g+2$ branch points of $f$ (where $g$ is the genus of $X$).

Edit: I wrote more details below.

Suppose $X$ is given by $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb C^2: y^2=k(x)\}$ locally. Then $f:X\to \Bbb C$ is locally given by $f(x,y)=x$. If $(x_0,y_0)$ is a ramification point of $f$, we must have $k(x_0)=0$ and $y_0=0$. At this point $(x_0,0)$, the coordinate $y$ can be served as a local coordinate. After choosing a chart near $g(x_0,0)$, we may assume $g$ is locally given by $y\mapsto g(y)\in \Bbb C$.

In summary, we are in the following situation: Suppose $g:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ is an even function, and $x=x(y):\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ is a degree 2 map ramified at $0$. And there is a map $h:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ such that $h(x(y))=g(y)$. How can we show that $h$ is holomorphic at $0$?

Comment: Constant functions are meromorphic, so you need to be more explicit that your maps are nonconstant.

Comment: @KCd Thanks. I've made an edit.

Comment: Meromorphic functions do not have branch points.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. I've made another edit to make the question specified in my situation.

Comment: Much clearer and much more explicit. Think in local coordinates around the ramification point. As a question in local complex analysis, if $h$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$ and $h(z)=h(-z)$, show that $h(z)=\phi(z^2)$ for some holomorphic $\phi$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've shown that using that the odd degree terms vanish in the Taylor series of an even function. But how can we get the result from it? I've added more details..

Comment: You have a convergent power series on a disk, hence a holomorphic function.